# Netsuite client script - Adding fields Dynamically

Tags: client, netsuite

In Netsuite, is it possible to have a client script that in field change it dynamically adds fields? My example would be you have a quantity field and once selected, and that number of fields to specify information about each item of the quantity (such as serial numbers)?

From what I have read I do not see anything that allows this, but I would like to know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot customize the form by using client script. The only things that you can do using client script are as follows :

• Initializing forms

• Entering or changing a value in a field (before and after it is entered)

• Entering or changing a value in a field that sources another field

• Selecting a line item on a sublist

• Adding a line item (before and after it is entered)

• Saving a form

• Searching for another record

• Loading, saving or deleting a record

You can use a user event to add fields to the form

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add fields to the form via client script.  You would need to add the field on the user event script before load.
However, you could add a hidden NS text field. Then your client script could prompt for a list of serial numbers for each. On your user event script you could parse that field for those numbers.